# How to add header title for every Section in Table

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have four sections in my UITableView, how do I add a header for each section? 
I am using the following code, but it's not working.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 

    if (section == 0) 
        return @"Tasks";

    if (section == 1) 
        return @"Appointments";

    if (section == 2) 
        return @"Activities";

    if (section == 3) 
        return @"Inactivities";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure that you've implemented [tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForHeaderInSection%3a)?

In your case the titles were actually set but the headers' heights were 0 by default. Add this `UITableViewDelegate` method if you haven't yet:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    return 40; //play around with this value
}
```

*P.S.: Consider using `switch` statement in such methods*

Comment: what is `@switch` and how is it different from `switch`?

Comment: There is no `@switch`. I assume it's a typo. ;)

Comment: sure, it was typo :) there is no `@switch`, just `switch`

Answer (score 4):

If your section Header height is constant for each section then you do'nt need to implement  `heightForHeaderInSection` delegate method, And you could use as below

```
myTableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 40 ;
```

In Apple Documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score -4):

Change your if statements like this

```
if(section == 0)
    return @"ABC";
else if (section == 1)
    return @"XYZ";
else
    return @"PQR"
```

I hope this helps. Please let me know if I can be of any more help.

Pinku:)